# Tropical Arithmetic and Numeral Systems - Number systems

Tags: tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

Is there some paper about Numeral Systems / Number Systems, using tools of Tropical Geometry to represent numbers? Maybe through Continuous fractions, triangular numbers, arithmetic functions, ...

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Maybe you can try to use some examples to illustrate?

Comment: Since most place-value notations number systems compress the information to represent a number by means of sums of powers("grouped product"). This concept but taken to tropical arithmetic, with mins of "grouped sums".